# Looping through different sample sizes

Tags: python, machine-learning

How can I loop through the different samples size with the aim of creating a dataframe for each so that I can be able to use in a model.
I attempted with the folllowing code but seems not to be yielding correct results. Is there an alternative way I can use in therms of different sample sizes so that they can be pass through a model.

```
def HiggsData_loader():
    higgs_arr = []
    X_dir2 = {}
    y_dir2 = {}
    sizes = [10000, 50000, 500000, 1000000]
    for s in  sizes:
        datasets =  pd.read_csv('./DATA/HIGGS.csv',header=None,nrows=s)
        y2 = datasets.values[:,0]
        X2 = datasets.values[:,1:]
    
        scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X2) #A scaler object
        X_scaled2 = scaler.transform(X2)

        higgs_arr.append('Higgs')
        X_dir2['Higgs'] = X_scaled2.copy()
        y_dir2['Higgs'] = y2.copy()
    
    return higgs_arr, X_dir2, y_dir2
```

I was expecting to pass through the different samples in the following code to measure the time.

```
md2 = {}
def processing_time(data,methods):
    for m in models:
        rd = {}
        for ds in Data_arr:
            X = X_dir[ds]
            y = y_dir[ds]
            kNN =  KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=50, algorithm = m)
            t_start = time.time()
            scores = cross_val_score(kNN, X, y, cv=2)
            t = time.time()-t_start
            rd[ds] = t
            print('\n',m + " Time: ",'\n', t)
        md2[m] = rd
    return md2
```

Comment: standard rule: if you use `for`-loop then you need list to keep all results. But you always put result to the same `x_dir2`,`y_dir2` so finally you get only last result.

Comment: at start you should create list ie `all_results = []` and inside loop you should create new ` `X_dir2 = {}`,`y_dir2 = {}` ad add values to these dictionares, next append them to list `all_results.append( [X_dir2, y_dir2] )`. and at the end you should `return all_results`.

Comment: I don't see how you use `HiggsData_loader()` in second code - and it may need different solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard rule: if you use `for`-loop then you need list to keep all results.

And you should

- create list for all results before loop, i.e `all_results = []`
- inside loop create new `higgs_arr`, `X_dir2`, `y_dir2`, add data and append all to list i.e `all_results.append( [higgs_arr, X_dir2, y_dir2] )`
- at the end use `return all_results`

And this way you get list with many results.

I don't know how you use `HiggsData_loader()` in `processing_time` so I don't know what changes it may need - so I show only `HiggsData_loader()`

It could look like this.

```
def HiggsData_loader():

    all_results = []

    sizes = [10000, 50000, 500000, 1000000]

    for s in  sizes:
        datasets =  pd.read_csv('./DATA/HIGGS.csv',header=None,nrows=s)
        y2 = datasets.values[:,0]
        X2 = datasets.values[:,1:]
    
        scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X2) #A scaler object
        X_scaled2 = scaler.transform(X2)

        higgs_arr = []
        X_dir2 = {}
        y_dir2 = {}

        higgs_arr.append('Higgs')
        X_dir2['Higgs'] = X_scaled2.copy()
        y_dir2['Higgs'] = y2.copy()
            
        all_results.append( [higgs_arr, X_dir2, y_dir2] )
    
    return all_results
```

And later you can use as

```
all_results = HiggsData_loader()

for higgs_arr, X_dir2, y_dir2 in all_results:
    # ... code ...
```

or directly

```
for higgs_arr, X_dir2, y_dir2 in HiggsData_loader():
    # ... code ...
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you use `HiggsData_loader()` directly in some `for`-loop then you could use original version but with `yield` instead of `return` but inside loop

```
def HiggsData_loader():
    sizes = [10000, 50000, 500000, 1000000]
    for s in  sizes:
        datasets =  pd.read_csv('./DATA/HIGGS.csv',header=None,nrows=s)
        y2 = datasets.values[:,0]
        X2 = datasets.values[:,1:]
    
        scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X2) #A scaler object
        X_scaled2 = scaler.transform(X2)

        higgs_arr = []
        X_dir2 = {}
        y_dir2 = {}

        higgs_arr.append('Higgs')
        X_dir2['Higgs'] = X_scaled2.copy()
        y_dir2['Higgs'] = y2.copy()
    
        yield higgs_arr, X_dir2, y_dir2  # inside loop
```

And then you can run as

```
for higgs_arr, X_dir2, y_dir2 in HiggsData_loader():
    # ... code ...
```

or you may need `list()` to get all values

```
all_results = list( HiggsData_loader() )

for higgs_arr, X_dir2, y_dir2 in all_results:
    # ... code ...
```

Comment: Thank You. The way you broke it down/explained is very insighful and helpful